# Windows on VirtualBox and special characters

Tags: keyboard, windows, virtualbox

I have a standard Apple US keyboard but I often have to type in German. I find the OS X shortcuts easy to remember and I am comfortable with them.

To type the umlauts you have to type <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (u as in *umlaut*) followed by the letter that needs the diacritic.

When I use Windows in VirtualBox I have to fall back to the Windows combinations (e.g.<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for ö) which I find difficult to remember (I don't use VirtualBox a lot).

Is there a way to map the usual OS X key combinations to Windows?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but according to the [VMware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1005578) you can install Apple versions of keyboard layouts on Windows by installing Boot Camp drivers.

Comment: If I try to install the BootCamp drivers in Windows 7 (Virtual Box) I get a message that they are unsupported.

Comment: in vmware there is a possibility to whitch key combos on mac acts as which on the vm's. maybe there is some thing similar to this on virtualbox.